# an expression of non boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected near in report query

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008-r2

how would i resolve that error.  I am sending in multiple values at 1 time which is causing the error.  Individual items not cause the error.  When i hit select all that is when the error comes in in ssrs report

```
SELECT        '**ALL Sites**' AS PlaceDesc, '%' AS PlaceID
where @termID = '%'
UNION
SELECT        'With Placement Availiability' AS PlaceDesc, 'pla' AS PlaceID
WHERE        (@termID <> '%' )


  -- WHERE        (@termID <> '%' and  a.termID IN(SELECT convert(VARCHAR(max), value) FROM --
string_split(@termID, ','))) <-- I tried this and it didnt work
    UNION
    SELECT        'With Students Assigned' AS PlaceDesc, 'stu' AS PlaceID
    WHERE        (@termID <> '%' )
   -- WHERE        ( @termID IN(SELECT convert(VARCHAR(max), value) FROM string_split(@termID, ',')))  <-- I tried this and it didnt work
```